# Use VPN ip address htttp Urlconnection java

Tags: java, networking, ip, vpn

I have openVPN Connect configured on a vista laptop, so that connecting with a web browser allows the computer to change its ip address. What are the steps necessary to allow the following networking code in java to use this new ip address:

```
HttpURLConnection x=(HttpURLConnection)new URL("google.com/search?sclient=psy-
ab&h1=en&site=&source=hp&q=ip%20address&btnG=Search").openConnection();
```

And then open an input   stream, read it in, and see one of the vpn addresses in the page, after the html: "Your public IP address is "

Comment: Is the Java running on the vista laptop, a server you're accessing via a web browser on the vista laptop, or other?

Comment: java is running through the ide on my vista laptop

Comment: Do you want the public IP address that you used to connect to the IP address, or the public IP address that you're seen as via the VPN?

Comment: the public address seen as via VPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without calling to an external service.

You will need to have your application call something like http://www.whatismyip.com/ and parse out the IP address the wider internet sees you as. There is probably a REST service you can call which gives you the answer back as XML/JSON/something more computer parseable.

Unfortunately, your local machine does not have enough information for Java to be able to find out without going external.